# Django webapp 500 server error after running migrations

Tags: python, django

So I ran python manage.py migrate after making some code changes, and I end up getting a 500 server error when I run the app. I tried reverting the migration files but that didn't work, and when I try to run migrate again it tells me that there are No migrations to apply. Any general suggestions?

Comment: you can delete your migrations folder and after it run migrations command again.

Comment: You need to provide more detail to get help. Are you running on local or production? What is the error related to the status 500?